# How to bind a view's width to the root view's width

Tags: android, xml, android-databinding

I want the width of my `ImageView` to be the same size as the device screen. Normally you would set the `layout_width` attribute to  `match_parent`. The problem is my `ImageView` is inside a `LinearLayout` which is inside a `HorizontalScrollView`. See Code Below

```
   <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/root_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:scrollbars="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/fragment_get_trending_image_backdrop1"
                android:layout_width='@{String.valueOf(rootLayout.width)+"dp"}'
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:src="@drawable/cassidy"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/backgrounds/scenic" />
//....other imageviews
```

I want to set the width of the `ImageView` to be the width of the root `LinearLayout` with id `root_layout` at runtime. Is this possible with android data binding? If there is another way to achieve the same please advise.

I am getting this error message when I try to compile

```
Could not resolve the two-way binding attribute 'width' on type 'android.widget.LinearLayout'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do what you are trying to do.
First of all, this could be an XY problem. What do you want to achieve?

Your `root_layout` has a margin - `android:layout_margin="16dp"`, so it's impossible that any of its children could exceed its bounds in a `LinearLayout`.

So, you could just set `android:layout_margin="0dp"` (or remove the attribute).

Also, it seems you are stacking a bunch of `ImageView` inside an `HorizontalScrollView`. You may want to use a `RecyclerView` or a `ViewPager2` instead.

Comment: The Recycler view seems to do the trick. Thanks What I was trying to achieve was trying to have the ImageView' width match the width of the user's device in the HorizontalScrollView.